# Linq IQueryable<model> Multiple filter values

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

### Table
Device_Models

**Model_Type** Field
Iphone x 64GB
Iphone x 32GB
Iphone 7 32GB
Iphone 8 128GB

I am using the below query to filter model type in the text box, the problem here that it does not return any value when I enter "iphone 64" in the search box. In SQL, the following "%iphone%64%" will return the correct data fitlering. How can I implement the "%iphone%64%" in Linq Query?

```
var query = (from M in db.Device_Models
                         join C in db.Device_Categories on M.Device_Category_ID equals C.Category_ID
                         join AC in db.AllowedCategories on C.Category_ID equals AC.allowedcategoryid
                         Where M.Model_Type.Contains(**searchcriteria**)
                         && M.IsEnabled == true 
                         && (from o in db.AllowedCategories select o.allowedcategoryid).Contains(C.Category_ID)
                         orderby M.Model_Type
                         select new model
                         {
                             Model_ID = M.Model_ID,
                             Manufacturer_ID_FK = (int)M.Manufacturer_ID_FK,
                             Device_Category_ID = (int)M.Device_Category_ID,
                             Model_Type = M.Model_Type,
                             ImageName = M.ImageName,
                             IsEnabled = (bool)M.IsEnabled,
                         }).Take(40);
```

Thank you

Comment: Just for a future note: please use markdown syntax to format your question. Instead of `<br>` for break line. If you select your code and press `Ctrl + k` it will format it as code.
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: of course will do. thank you.

Comment: With EF 6.x you can use `DbFunctions.Like` as a method so `DbFunctions.Like(M.Model_Type, $"%{filter.Replace(' ','%')}$")`